# Ogg FLAC demuxer for Aurora/flac.js

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, ogg, flac, aurora.js

The [Aurora project](https://github.com/audiocogs/aurora.js) with [flac.js](https://github.com/audiocogs/flac.js) provides FLAC decoding and playback with JavaScript.  The [demuxer in flac.js](https://github.com/audiocogs/flac.js/blob/master/src/demuxer.js) appears to only support native FLAC.

Before I go off and re-invent the wheel, is there a JavaScript demuxer for FLAC within an Ogg stream?

Comment: I can't say I have ever seen FLAC encoded in Ogg.

Comment: @greg-449 It's the only usable way for FLAC radio streams.  Here's an example stream:  http://radio.cesnet.cz:8000/cro-d-dur.flac  The streaming server needs to be able to align streaming chunks as it sends them to the client.  Native FLAC streams have an undetermined frame size meaning that it isn't possible for a server to simply inspect the frame header for the length and chunk it accordingly.  The only way to determine native FLAC frame size is to decode the audio, which is impractical and slow on the streaming server.  If you encapsulte FLAC in Ogg, this problem goes away.